# Data sharing between two applications

Tags: android

Recently i had an interview in which the question was asked as "How would you be able to share the data between two installed apps or apk's?"

I didn't have any answer for this question. Can anyone help me in determining an way to do so...

Answer (score 33, accepted):

[ContentProviders](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html) are a good approach to share data between applications.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Sorry to ask, but can you be more specific on how to share the data. Any example will be of great help

Comment: [This is a nice simple example](http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/64.html), using a system datasource that's available to all apps. [Download sample](http://marakana.com/static/tutorials/ContentUserDemo.zip)

Comment: @BradParks link was dead

Comment: @RanjithKumar - Good catch! I haven't tried it, but this appears to be the same sample from a different source: [overview](https://newcircle.com/s/post/64/contentprovider_user_demo) and download:[mirror 1](https://thenewcircle.com/static/tutorials/ContentUserDemo.zip) and [mirror 2](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/274922/ContentUserDemo.zip)

Comment: @Roflcoptr, what if a password is to be shared between two of my apps? What's the best way to do that?

Answer (score 34):

> **Edit - 28-Mar-2023**
>
> It's deprecated, please consider other answers to solve your problem.

**Send data from Application 1 (for ex:Application 1 package name is "com.sharedpref1" ).**

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("demopref",
                    Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
            editor.putString("demostring", strShareValue);
            editor.commit();
```

**Receive the data in Application 2( to get data from Shared Preferences in Application 1).**

```
    try {
            con = createPackageContext("com.sharedpref1", 0);//first app package name is "com.sharedpref1"
            SharedPreferences pref = con.getSharedPreferences(
                        "demopref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            String your_data = pref.getString("demostring", "No Value");
        } 
    catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
                Log.e("Not data shared", e.toString());
         }
```

**In both application manifest files add same shared user id & label,**

```
 android:sharedUserId="any string" 
 android:sharedUserLabel="@string/any_string"
```

both are same... and shared user label must from string.xml

**like this example.**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.xxxx"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0"
android:sharedUserId="any string" 
android:sharedUserLabel="@string/any_string">
```

Comment: don't you have to sign the apps with the same key too?

Comment: Very nicely explained. Its working. Thanks buddy :-)

Comment: @Ranjith Kumar I am get "No Value" what reason to doesn't get pass the key value

Comment: @Ramprasathselvam are you follow my all steps? please read step by step and implement. surely it works

Comment: @RanjithKumar thanks im achieve that. my problem was shareuserid finally i'm fix that

Comment: @RanjithKumar how to access sqlite db data send 1 to 2

Comment: @Ramprasathselvam sorry no idea. You can go with contentproviders

Comment: Worked perfectly !!

Comment: Please see: MODE_WORLD_READABLE: https://android.i-visionblog.com/working-with-android-shared-preferences-4668efa298a8. It is deprecated so use FileProvider: https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/share-file for latest OS devices.

Comment: Shortest Way I could find. Liked this. :)

Comment: @RanjithKumar Visited this post late with some specific requirements. Just a small doubt, if I put such mechanism for some test app on my release app, how can I ensure that the pref is not read by some other app by defining same string?

Comment: **sharedUserId** and **sharedUserLabel** [deprecated](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element#uid) in `api 29`.

Comment: Changing sharedUserId is a bad idea - if you change this from one build to another, any users that had the previous build without the ID won't be able to update the app without uninstalling it first.

Comment: @JCutting8 it's deprecated. I posted this answer long time ago. Ignore this

Answer (score 7):

If you want to share data between applications, make sure you sign with the same key:

> Code/data sharing through permissions – The Android system provides
>   signature-based permissions enforcement, so that an application can
>   expose functionality to another application that is signed with a
>   specified certificate. By signing multiple applications with the same
>   certificate and using signature-based permissions checks, your
>   applications can share code and data in a secure manner.

This is quoted from: [android developer page about signing](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html)

If it's a small amount of data you could send it through an intent.

Comment: can you point out how to fetch or retrieve data from one app to another? That link is more about signing.

Answer (score 5):

I suspect they were likely looking for Android specific methods such as the content provider answer.

Other alternatives...
Android Specific - Remote services
General - TCP/IP connections
General - Writing to a location on the SD card

Care to hear more about a specific method?

Also stealing this question for an interview today :)

Answer (score 3):

Content provider is the android component, which has to be used if one application wants to share its data with other application.

Note: Files, SqliteDatabases, Sharedpreference files created by an application is private to only that application. Other application can't directly access it. If programmer exposes database by using content provider, then only that data is accessible to other applications. To communicate with content provider use content resolver.

Comment: Of all the answers here, I find your answer good for better understanding conceptually. Tq

Answer (score 0):

My requirement was to send a simple string from one app to another and get a string back. Like "user id" from App1 to App2 and get "username" back to App1. I was able to achieve this using **implicit intent** and **startActivityForResult**. If anyone is looking for the full process I posted my answer here [How to send data between one application to other application in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38608496/how-to-send-data-between-one-application-to-other-application-in-android/56737554#56737554).

App1 > MainActivity.java

```
        //Need to register your intent filter in App2 in manifest file with same action.
        intent.setAction("com.example.sender.login"); // <packagename.login>
        intent.setType("text/plain");
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);

        onActivityResult(...) {
           ...
           // Handle received data from App2 here
        }
```

I had two activity in App2 ie. MainActivity and LoginActivity.

App2 > AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <intent-filter>
        <!--The action has to be same as App1-->
        <action android:name="com.example.sender.login" />
        ...
    </intent-filter>
```

App2 > LoginActivity.java

```
override fun onResume() {
    ...
    // Handle data from App1 here
}

fun onClickBack(view: View) {
    val intent = intent
    ...
    // Set data in bundle here for App1
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent)
    finish()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. using implicit intent and startActivityForResult.
2. Using Content provider

[eg of content Providor:](http://content%20providor%20example)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ContentProviders](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html) to share files, or you can use a **Service** with [Android Interface Definition Language (AIDL)](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl) to create a programming interface to communicate with each other.

For Android 11 (API level 30) you may also need to specify a query with the package of the app you want to interact with:

```
<manifest package="com.example.app">
  <queries>
    <!-- Specific apps you interact with, eg: -->
    <package android:name="com.example.service" />
  </queries>
  ...
</manifest>
```