# Retrieving Data from another running android app

Tags: android

I am building an application where I would like to have a heart rate over a certain threshold trigger and event. I'm wondering if there's any way to do this by using data retrieved by another app on the phone (heart rate app) in my own application. I would rather not have to build a heart rate sensor from scratch!!

For example, using data from an app like this : 
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.macropinch.hydra.android&hl=en

Can I even do this? Or do I need a developers permission, or is the data output to files on the phone I can just read?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> I'm wondering if there's any way to do this by using data retrieved
> ```
>
> by another app on the phone (heart rate app) in my own application

If other application is providing remote service (look AIDL) then your application can call that service to achieve functionality.but AFAIK Cardiograph doesn't provide such service.

> Or do I need a developers permission, or is the data outputted to
>   files on the phone I can just read?

The only option i see here is to obtain Souce Code for that obviously you need to contact developer :D

If this application is outputing data on SD card then you can read it.

Comment: I followed your suggestion and received source code from a developer of a heart rate app and I am now modifying his application to work with mine! Thanks to both answers!

Comment: haha Cheers!! let me know your application name i will download it :)

Answer (score 2):

This is already discussed in another thread. Threre are mainly two methods, one is contentprovider and the other is sharedpreferences. But app that provides data should implement those. [Data sharing between two applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5745243/data-sharing-between-two-applications)