# Send string to another Android application

Tags: java, android

How can I pass a String between applications? The String is some field that is known in the sender app and is needed by the receiver app. Both applications are on the same Device.

Comment: You can use [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html).

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11353195/passing-string-data-between-android-applications

Comment: i think content provider to this task or u can achieve this task through using content provider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with intents passing the string value in the URL, specifically: http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html.

Gotten from: [Passing String data between Android applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11353195/passing-string-data-between-android-applications)