# Android sending string from my application to any other applications

Tags: java, android, service, sendkeys

I have a service application.  I need to send a string to any application (browser, word, ...wherever the keyboard cursor focused). How can I do this?

```
//onReceive of my service onStartCommand...
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String textToSend = intent.getStringExtra("data");
    if(textToSend!=null && textToSend.length()>0) {

        //Here I need send "textToSend" to another application 

    }else{
        Toast.makeText(context, "Error! ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: why do you think that *any application* will accept your string?

Comment: Related, I believe: [How to use Accessibility Services for “Taking Action for Users”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42125940/how-to-use-accessibility-services-for-taking-action-for-users)

Comment: @Vladyslav Matviienko any application that accept text as input...!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it with `Intents`. Passing the string value in the URL, specifically: http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html.

---

You can check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11353195/passing-string-data-between-android-applications) for more info.

Comment: Thanks, but not work for me. I need send the string to word, for example.