# Share data between android applications

Tags: android, keychain

I want to share data between different Android applications. On iOS applications I use the Keychain with an accessGroup property so the data is only accessible from my applications plus the data remains even if I delete all applications.

What mechanism can I use to do the same on Android?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: possible duplicate of [Data sharing between two applications](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5745243/data-sharing-between-two-applications)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [ContentProviders](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html).  [Here](http://www.androidcompetencycenter.com/2009/01/basics-of-android-part-iv-android-content-providers/) is a good tutorial on ContentProviders. And [this](http://codeoncloud.blogspot.in/2012/06/data-sharing-between-two-android.html) post specifically tells about data sharing using it.

Answer (score 1):

[`ContentProviders` are the way to go](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html) on Android for sharing data between apps.

From the Android tutorials:

> Content providers manage access to a structured set of data. They encapsulate the data, and provide mechanisms for defining data security. Content providers are the standard interface that connects data in one process with code running in another process.

Answer (score 1):

Use [ContentProviders](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html) to do that.