# Service put and get some data

Tags: android, service

I have two applications. One run service and second is only small app. I want to put some data to service in first app, but I want to get this data in second app. How can I do that? I need that because when I use home button on second app and return I need check if id was changed. I think about run service with id in first app and second app when onResume check that id.

This is code service class:

```
public class ServiceId extends Service{

    private int id;
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {
        id = MainActivity.getApplicationId();
        Log.v("Start", "Webservice started");
    }
}
```

I start service in mainactivity:

startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, ServiceId.class));

how get that id in other application?

Comment: you do it by using sharedpreference

Comment: what kind of data, are those apps on the same device...

Comment: I want to send only one integer id. I need that because in onResume from second app I must get this data.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Data sharing between two applications](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5745243/data-sharing-between-two-applications)