# How to pass data from one application to another in android

Tags: android

Can any one tell me how to `pass data through bundle or any thing` else between `two installed application`s in android?

I have googled around but could not get any proper guide

I give a try to [Content Provider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html) As suggested on some similar such query [Data sharing between two applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5745243/data-sharing-between-two-applications) but i am very much new to content provider, I try to get some thinng from official documents but could not get succeeded

Thanks Any way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may simply use a `BroadcastReceiver`. If you follow the `Android` tag, you'll notice how usually it's recommended using local `BroadcastReceiver`s and local `sendBroadcasts()`. In your case you need **global** `BroadcastReceiver`s so you can comunnicate at inter-app level. I'd recommend using custom `Actions` to broadcast, as Android system's might cause missfunctions if you don't handle them well.

Broadcasts use `Intent`s to communicate.

More info on `BroadcastReceiver` [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html), and you'll find a very good example [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html).

Answer (score 3):

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
intent.setComponent(ComponentName.unflattenFromString("another app package name"));
intent.addCategory("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putInt("key", 1);
intent.putExtras(bundle);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 2):

For sharing data android offers the [Intent](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html) class.

Answer (score 1):

if you mean two separated applications 
You can write data to file from one application and read the file from other application

Comment: Not the best solution. Where you locate this file?

Comment: in a path in Application project

Comment: using sharedPrefarance we can achive with same key

Comment: MODE_WORLD_READABLE: Creating world-readable files is very dangerous, and likely to cause security holes in applications. It is strongly discouraged; instead, applications should use more formal mechanism for interactions such as ContentProvider, BroadcastReceiver, and Service. There are no guarantees that this access mode will remain on a file, such as when it goes through a backup and restore. File creation mode: allow all other applications to have read access to the created file.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#MODE_WORLD_READABLE