# Data sharing between two application in android

Tags: android

I have two application..

One for main application.. another one for title changer..

If I enter the title in one application it affected in another application..

***What I am tried,***

I already done by store database in SD card..And refer title using DBHelper.

***My problem,***

But now my database moved into main application.. so I cannot refer database from title changer application.

***My question,***

**Without database creation can I pass data between two application..like intent or shared preferences?**

Note: both application stored in same device..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Data sharing between two applications](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5745243/data-sharing-between-two-applications)

Comment: And even better reading: https://developer.android.com/training/building-content-sharing.html

Comment: if your apps work together you can use sharedUserId

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Send data from Application 1 (for ex:Application 1 package name is "com.sharedpref1" ).**

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("demopref",
                    Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
            editor.putString("demostring", strShareValue);
            editor.commit();
```

**Receive the data in Application 2( to get data from Shared Preferences in Application 1).**

```
    try {
            con = createPackageContext("com.sharedpref1", 0);//first app package name is "com.sharedpref1"
            SharedPreferences pref = con.getSharedPreferences(
                        "demopref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            String your_data = pref.getString("demostring", "No Value");
        } 
    catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
                Log.e("Not data shared", e.toString());
         }
```

**In both application manifest files add same shared user id & label,**

```
 android:sharedUserId="any string" 
 android:sharedUserLabel="@string/any_string"
```

both are same... and shared user label must from string.xml

**like this example.**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.xxxx"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0"
android:sharedUserId="any string" 
android:sharedUserLabel="@string/any_string">
```

Comment: how to do with same android app but install on two different devices???

Comment: @Pranita can you tell your exact need? If we need to communicate device to device use wifi,bluetooth,web-service,or firebase(Even same app). we can't use intent or sharedPreferences

Comment: @RanjithKumar i am getting "No value"

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple ways to achieve this.

1. Usage of [Content Providers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html)
2. Shared Preferences with [MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#MODE_WORLD_READABLE)
3. Whenever content is changed in one app, send a broadcast intent which can be read by the other app using a receiver.

Comment: thanks for your answer.. I get answer from your 2nd point..But it cannot used in api level 17..

Comment: Oh! My bad, I didn't know that it's deprecated.

Comment: BTW, CONTEXT_IGNORE_SECURITY and MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE share same constant value 2. So you might use it as it's not deprecated.

Comment: Context.MODE_PRIVATE is secure & professional... I get answer.. see my answer below..

Comment: Great! I never knew about shared ids.

Answer (score -1):

You can use intents.
You can send an intent from an Activity to an Activity in another Application and pass data as "Extras" in the sending intent.
You have to create a new activity that uses a custom action with the default category.
Chech [Android Intents - Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)

Comment: An Intent is a messaging object you can use to request an action from another app component (Activities,Services,Recievers...) not only for the same application.