# Reading/Writing text from edittext in another application

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

Greetings guys.
Recently, I was wondering if there are any methods to get instance of the focused Edittext on the screen even if it's from another application.
In C# we were able to do it by digging into the Windows API and putting FindWindow or FindWindowEx functions into practice.
Is there any alternatives in Java for android?
Thanks guys.

Comment: Past it with an intent when you go to open the other application.

Comment: Thank you Alex but actually, it was not what I was asking. I updated my question to make it more clear.

Comment: This seems like if possible it would be a huge security flaw. Any app can read your passwords! etc. I am glad it's not possible.

Answer (score 1):

If you are thinking to get the value of EditText of one application from a different application then, I'm sorry it's not possible unless both the application has same signatures. Applications which have different signatures can not access their datas due to security restriction. However, if both the application has same signature then you can store the value inside a file or database, then other application can access the data. If you need more details how you can share data between various applications, [see this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5745243/data-sharing-between-two-applications).