# How to transfer data from one app to another app in android

Tags: java, android, mobile

So, what I need here is to send data from App1 to App2. I've tried with simple code that I've made, but something is wrong here. I want to make a simple input on 1 editText in app1 then it will be received by app2.

Example :

App1 : EditText -> I input 'Hello!'

Then

App2 : TextView -> 'Hello!'

But what happens next, the textview in App2 does not show anything. What's wrong here?

These are my code that I've tried.

My Application 1:

```
secondAppButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.secondAppButton);
    namaEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.namaEditText);

    secondAppButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String nama = namaEditText.getText().toString();

            Intent secondApp = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.example.yosua.myapplication2");
            Bundle bundleApp = new Bundle();

            bundleApp.putString("namaOrang", nama);
            secondApp.putExtras(bundleApp);

            startActivity(secondApp);
        }
    });
```

My Application 2:

```
namaDariApp1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.namaApp2);

    String nama;

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

    nama = extras.getString("namaOrang");
    namaDariApp1.setText(nama);
```

Comment: Did you fix this and how?

Answer (score 0):

Try including the key

```
secondApp.putExtras("key",bundleApp);
```

And retrieve it like this

```
Bundle extras = intent.getBundleExtra("key");
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to options to pass a value between two applications, The first one is by using [ContentProviders](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html) are a good approach to share data between applications, or you can use a SharedPreferences something like this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29170236/2593672)