# How to set global flag in android sytem during multiple apps?

Tags: android, file

I meet one case: my several apps(app-A, app-B, app-C) may run on same andorid device. But I need to send just once notification per day during these apps. My design is to use a gloal flag like create a empty file with date like: notify_file_2017_01_07, But It may encounter the conrrent problem. So is there a good solution to set system global flag like this ?

Actually this is different with: [Data sharing between two applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5745243/data-sharing-between-two-applications), it's about how to set gloal sharing flag in multiple apps, but not to exchange data between two apps.

Comment: I am having a similar problem on android with react-native context. I checked [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5745243/data-sharing-between-two-applications) answer several times but it did not help. I am using [this component](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-keychain/blob/master/android/src/main/java/com/oblador/keychain/KeychainModule.java) for this purpose. However I could not share a single data point among multiple apps. I am using `SharedPreferences`, `sharedUserId` etc. but no config did help me.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into [ContentProviders](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html). They are pretty standard to share data between apps.

Comment: In my understanding, ContentProvider just allow other apps to get the data of self app( app-A acces app-B),  cause ContentProvider belows one app. It's little different for my case.