# How to share private data between multiple apps by same developer

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, accountmanager, android-productflavors

I am facing a problem where I need to store sensitive data where it will accessible to all of my apps, but not to the other apps. I know one way where we set same "SharedUSerId" to all the apps. But this is not possible now because one of our app, which does not have any SharedUSerId set, is already in production. If I change the SharedUserId now, the users won't be able to update the app.
Is there any way to have a private storage which is accessible to only the apps signed with same signature?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5745243/data-sharing-between-two-applications

Comment: Use custom `signature`-level permissions to defend your preferred IPC channel (`ContentProvider`, `Service`, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

You can use your own custom designed Intent filters. So your other apps may send a broadcast on which you are listening to.

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters